# Call a current visible NavHostFragment's method from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, android-jetpack-navigation

To achieve this task, I am currently using a FragmentListner interface, but I need to use create a static method to get the instance of the fragment. To avoid this approach of static way, I am thinking if there is any better way to do it. I need to get the current visible fragment instance on the Activity and based upon that I need to call a method of that fragment.

If it is not a NavHost fragment I am getting easily the instance of fragment like this below and can call any public method from it.

```
    Fragment fragment = getCurrentFragment();
    if (fragment instanceof MyFragment) {
                ((MyFragment) fragment).doFragmentOperation();
      }

    private Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
       return this.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.framelayout);
      }
```

But I am able to know which fragment is visible by addOnDestinationChangedLisnter method like below

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
          
            switch (destination.getId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_x:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "X fragment is visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_y:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Y fragment is visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_z:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Z fragment is visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Here we can able to know the visible fragment by destination id, is there anything which can return us the visible fragment instance directly??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `NavHostFragment` to get the `primaryNavigationFragment` using its `childFragmentManager`.

```kotlin
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.your_nav_host_fragment_id) as NavHostFragment
val currentFragment = navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment
```

See if this works for you!

Comment: Yes, it did work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question seems a little bit unclear, are you using Navigation components?

If so, it's too easy: Just add an `navController.addOnDestinationChangeListener()` and you will always know the current `Fragment` in the activity.

If not, you can use `findLast` from `supportFragmentManager`:

```kotlin
supportFragmentManager.fragments.findLast { fgm -> //fragment that is currently on top }
```

Comment: Hey I am using  navController.addOnDestinationChangeListener()  but there we can able to know the visible fragment by destination id, is there anything which can return us the visible fragment instance directly?? I edited the question please have a look

Comment: once you have it, just ask for `findFragmentById(id)` and should be fine. Not sure what that returns, but I m sure that you can at least cast it to your fragment

Comment: No it did not work